# Arch Linux: Using wpa_supplicant to connect to wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, arch-linux, wpa-supplicant, wpa, wpa2

I was in the middle of switching desktop environments, so networkmanager had just been uninstalled, everything was fine because its instance was still running in the background. But I was with a friend and they jokingly closed my laptop lid, this locked my laptop and since gdm had just been removed I cloudnt sign in. Now I have no WiFi and my laptop is not capable of ethernet.

Everything would normally be fine but I can't seem to authenticate with my router using wpa_supplicant. I believe the protocol is not correct but I don't have iw installed so I can't check the protocol of my router. Any idea what I should do now?

**thanks to dirkt**

I was read the docs, which is where I should have started, my biggest issue was I didn't know how to use wpa_cli. Got it to work tho, pretty sure the issue is that my WiFi appears twice with the same ssid for 5ghz and 2.4ghz but after I used wpa_cli it started working right away thx dirkt

Comment: I've been using only wpa_supplicant to connect to WiFi for probably more than a decade (though in Debian) on multiple machines, so I can assure you that it works fine in principle. To debug why it doesn't work in your case is impossible with the information you've given in the question (basically none). In general, read the docs provided by wpa_supplicant, use `wpa_cli`, and make a proper configuration file as described in the docs (or enter all the necessary data with `wpa_cli`, but making a configuration file is easier).

Comment: You also don't really need to know the **protocol** of the router (that's advertised in the beacon, or you could check it on the router itself using a different computer). What you *do* need is the password. You can see the SSID with `wpa_cli`.